# Very odd, unknown cause of Internal Server Error

Tags: php, mysql, function, internal-server-error

When I request this function

```
    //Add the content to the database
function articleadd() {
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO site_content (title,content,reference,author,userid,authorip,day,month,year,token) VALUES ('$title','$articlebody','$reference','$author','$userid','$ipaddress','$day','$month','$year','$token')");
}
```

For some unknown reason it produces a Internal Server Error. I honestly have no idea why, I request this function below and it works fine

```
    //Add a message if the user is not logged in
function message() {
mysql_query("INSERT INTO messages (from,to,subject,content,type,ip) VALUES ('$userid','$userid','The content $title is pending completion.','A article was attempted to be saved, however when the we tried to saved it there was no-one logged in. As a result we saved the article but quarantined it so it will not show on the website. To correct this error, please click the link below, review the article and confirm it should display on the site. <a href=$url>$url</a>','$type','$ipaddress')");

}
```

With both I am requesting them one after the other as follows

```
    articleadd()
    message()
```

I have, in the function which does not work replaced all the mysql query with a very simple

```
    echo "hello world";
```

And yet I get the error.

I have tried copying and pasting things even the word "function" to make sure I am not making a silly mistake. I unfortunately do not have access to the Server Log with my hosting provider. Lastly I am aware that I am not passing the variables, and that is a separate issue, but on the basis that one works with out variables and the "hello world" test this can not be the issue.

Comment: I get worried when I see PHP code not using [PHP Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) to prevent [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) vulnerabilities. I hope you are sanitizing your variables in code that hasn't been pasted here. If not, please consider re-writing the code to use PDO Prepared Statements rather than trying to sanitize your variables.

Comment: Does a simple [`phpinfo()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php) script execute correctly?

Comment: What if `$title` is `You're Not Escaping Your SQL`? **Do not use** the `mysql_query` function. Use PDO as @sarnold suggests.

Comment: 1) Before doing anything else, check your server logs for any relevent error messsages.  2) Next, if you don't see anything conclusive, verify that *anything* works.  "phpinfo();" is a great way to do this.  3) Finally, failing all else, "divide and conquer".  Go to something "simple" that works.  Add things a bit at a time until it breaks.  Then fix it :)

Comment: Firstly I am sanitizing all variables don't worry. Interestingly `phpinfo()` works - but as soon as I change it to echo `"hello world";` it stops again, anyone explain why that would be?

Comment: @paulsm4 I have tried building it up and have copied the my_sql query from the previous function where it works fine but in this function it belly flops

Comment: I do not know how second query works, because 'FROM' and 'TO' are MySQL reserved words, you should quote them with backtick (`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As i can see, there is no values for the variables used inside the functions.
You need to set the values of the variables like $userid, $author, $title from parameters or global variables

```
function articleadd($title,$articlebody,$reference,$author,$userid,$ipaddress,$day,$month,$year,$token) {
mysql_query("INSERT INTO site_content (title,content,reference,author,userid,authorip,day,month,year,token) VALUES ('$title','$articlebody','$reference','$author','$userid','$ipaddress','$day','$month','$year','$token')");}
```

And call the function like this

```
articleadd('title','articlebody','reference','author','userid','ipaddress','day','month','year','token');
```